# Can this be made more pythonic?

Tags: python, primes

I came across this (really) simple program a while ago. It just outputs the first x primes.  I'm embarrassed to ask, is there any way to make it more "pythonic" ie condense it while making it (more) readable? Switching functions is fine; I'm only interested in readability.

Thanks

```
from math import sqrt


def isprime(n):
  if n ==2:
    return True
  if n % 2 ==0 : # evens
    return False

  max = int(sqrt(n))+1 #only need to search up to sqrt n 
  i=3
  while i <= max: # range starts with 3 and for odd i
    if n % i == 0:
      return False
    i+=2

  return True



reqprimes = int(input('how many primes: '))
primessofar = 0
currentnumber = 2
while primessofar < reqprimes:

  result = isprime(currentnumber)

  if result:
     primessofar+=1
     print currentnumber
     #print '\n'

  currentnumber += 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your algorithm itself may be implemented pythonically, but it's often useful to re-write algorithms in a functional way - You might end up with a completely different but more readable solution at all (which is even more pythonic).

```
def primes(upper):
    n = 2; found = []
    while n < upper:
        # If a number is not divisble through all preceding primes, it's prime
        if all(n % div != 0 for div in found):
            yield n
            found.append( n )
        n += 1
```

Usage:

```
for pr in primes(1000):
    print pr
```

Or, with Alasdair's comment taken into account, a more efficient version:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import takewhile

def primes(upper):
    n = 2; foundPrimes = []
    while n < upper:
        sqrtN = int(sqrt(n))
        # If a number n is not divisble through all preceding primes up to sqrt(n), it's prime
        if all(n % div != 0 for div in takewhile(lambda div: div <= sqrtN, foundPrimes)):
            yield n
            foundPrimes.append(n)
        n += 1
```

Comment: But please use `set()` for found instead of a list. This way it will be as slow as O(n*log) instead of as O(n^2).

Comment: @isagalaev: Er, no - you're wrong. You'll need to traverse any of the primes, not lookup one. In fact the list if more efficient since adding an element is O(1) instead of O(log n),

Comment: The `all` statement is inefficient - you only need to check for `div<=sqrt(n)`

Answer (score 6):

The given code is not very efficient. Alternative solution (just as inefficient):<sup>†</sup>

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> def is_prime(n):
...     return all(n % d for d in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1))
... 
>>> def primes_up_to(n):
...     return filter(is_prime, range(2, n))
... 
>>> list(primes_up_to(20))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

This code uses [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#all), [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range), [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#int), [`math.sqrt`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/math.html#math.sqrt), [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#filter) and [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#list). It is not completely identical to your code, as it prints primes *up to* a certain number, not exactly *n* primes. For that, you can do:

```
>>> from itertools import count, islice
>>> def n_primes(n):
...     return islice(filter(is_prime, count(2)), n)
... 
>>> list(n_primes(10))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

That introduces another two functions, namely [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). (That last piece of code works only in Python 3.x; in Python 2.x, use [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) instead of `filter`.)

---

<sup>†</sup>: A more efficient method is to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 5):

A few minor things from the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Uses four spaces, not two. (Personally I prefer tabs, but that's not the Pythonic way.)

Fewer blank lines.

Consistent whitespace: `n ==2:` => `n == 2:`

Use underscores in your variables names: `currentnumber` => `current_number`

Comment: Also, using 'max' as a variable name is discouraged as it covers up the builtin max function.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should not assign max to a variable as it is an inbuilt function used to find the maximum value from an iterable. Also, that entire section of code can instead be written as

```
for i in xrange(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
    if n%i==0: return False
```

Also, instead of defining a new variable result and putting the value returned by isprime into it, you can just directly do

```
if isprime(currentnumber):
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently found [Project Euler solutions in functional python](http://pyeuler.wikidot.com/start) and it has some really nice examples of working with primes like this. [Number 7](http://pyeuler.wikidot.com/problems-1-10) is pretty close to your problem:

```
def isprime(n):
    """Return True if n is a prime number"""
    if n < 3:
        return (n == 2)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    elif any(((n % x) == 0) for x in xrange(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2)):
        return False
    return True

def primes(start=2):
    """Generate prime numbers from 'start'"""
    return ifilter(isprime, count(start))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't use while loops for simple things like this. You rather create a range object and get the elements from there. So you could rewrite the first loop to this for example:

```
for i in range( 3, int( sqrt( n ) ) + 1, 2 ):
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
```

And it would be a lot better if you would cache your prime numbers and only check the previous prime numbers when checking a new number. You can save a lot time by that (and easily calculate larger prime numbers this way). Here is some code I wrote before to get all prime numbers up to `n` easily:

```
def primeNumbers ( end ):
    primes = []
    primes.append( 2 )

    for i in range( 3, end, 2 ):
        isPrime = True

        for j in primes:
            if i % j == 0:
                isPrime = False
                break

        if isPrime:
            primes.append( i )

    return primes

print primeNumbers( 20 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more pythonic with sieve algorithm (all primes small than 100):

```
def primes(n):
    sieved = set()
    for i in range(2, n):
        if not(i in sieved):
            for j in range(i + i, n, i):
                sieved.add(j)
    return set(range(2, n)) - sieved

print primes(100)
```

A very small trick will turn it to your goal.

Comment: What trick? Do you mean count & like double the number if #primes is too low? I can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Translated from the brilliant guys at [stacktrace.it](http://stacktrace.it/2008/01/progetto-eulero-problema-3/) (Daniele Varrazzo, specifically), this version takes advantage of [a binary min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) to solve this problem:

```
from heapq import heappush, heapreplace

def yield_primes():
    """Endless prime number generator."""

    # Yield 2, so we don't have to handle the empty heap special case
    yield 2

    # Heap of (non-prime, prime factor) tuples.
    todel = [ (4, 2) ]

    n = 3
    while True:
        if todel[0][0] != n:
            # This number is not on the head of the heap: prime!
            yield n
            heappush(todel, (n*n, n))   # add to heap

        else:
            # Not prime: add to heap
            while todel[0][0] == n:
                p = todel[0][1]
                heapreplace(todel, (n+p, p))
                # heapreplace pops the minimum value then pushes: 
                # heap size is unchanged

        n += 1
```

*This code isn't mine and I don't understand it fully ([but the explaination is here](http://stacktrace.it/2008/01/progetto-eulero-problema-3/) :) ), so I'm marking this answer as community wiki.*